# Hibernate Envers: No delete entry in audit table for cascading deletes

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade, hibernate-envers, cascading-deletes

I'm using Hibernate envers to track all changes made to my database objects. These objects are sometimes related by a (uni-directional) parent-child relationship. Because I need queries that are supposed to list all deleted objects, I'm relying on the audit table on envers to mark deleted objects (revtype column in *_aud table). However, these entries don't seem to be created for any of my child objects when their parent object gets deleted.

My object class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class MyClass {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 1024)
private String name;

    // An object can have exactly one parent, but multiple children
@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private MyClass parent;

}
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the cascade delete action that somehow bypasses hibernate envers. How can I achieve that the entries in the audit table for the children objects are created while still making sure that all children get automatically deleted by the database when the referenced parent is deleted?

Comment: What are the versions for Hibernate and Envers that you are using?

Comment: Currently, I'm using 3.5.2 Hibernate distribution. I just tried out 3.5.6, but I am getting the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using @OnDelete *and* generating the DDL via Hibernate? If so, Hibernate will add a "on cascade delete" on the relationship, meaning that the deletion of the children will take place outside Hibernate. So, Envers (or Hibernate) won't have access to this event, failing to act on that.

Comment: Yes, the DDL schema is created via Hibernate, the delete rule on the relationship is "cascade". Envers not having access to the delete event is what I was suspecting. So what's the right way to do this then?

Comment: I think the event is not cascading because you are marking it in the child perspective. So, I would add a property `private List<MyClass> children`, annotated with `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")`. Then, whenever you delete a parent, the children will get deleted too.

Comment: After some thought, I have decided to delete the children programmatically, because there are some other issues which require me to check the children when they are deleted. Anyway, thank you for your help.